# Have a Google sheets script run in the background

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I already have a script in place that sends out a notification when a new cell has been added to my spreadsheet. However, it only runs when I trigger it (through code editor) and does not run in the background. Essentially, I want to have this script run when something new is added to the spreadsheet, however, I'm unsure If this can be accomplished?

```
function sendNotification() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //Get Active cell
      var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
      var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
      var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
  //Define Notification Details
      var recipients = "rkarimov@webmd.net";
      var subject = "THIS IS A TEST - Please Ignore "+ss.getName();
      var body = ss.getName() + " has been updated.  Visit " + ss.getUrl() + " to view the changes.";
  //Check to see if column is A or B to trigger
      if (cellcol == 1)
      {
  //Send the Email
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
      }
  //End sendNotification
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Search Triggers in the documentation. You'd  need a installable trigger (Caution: It runs as you under your authorization)

Comment: If you simply want to be notified when the sheet is updated, I think you can use `Tools > Notification Rules ` and set up an email notification.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a new cell has been added".  Do you mean edited?  If so the onEdit(e) function will be triggered when the user enters a new value in a cell.  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/.  You can check for a specific cell on a specific sheet and limit the trigger only when that cell is changed.

Comment: Also, you may find that scripts that run from a trigger can't send an email: From documentation: `[Simple triggers] cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, ...`

Comment: @JohnRC I'm trying to send the email to a DL email (teamemail@org.com), so I believe the only way to accomplish this is through a custom function?